# Error : There are multiple root elements - Randomly

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, xml

Below is my code to get the interior feature values  and load them in to XML for parsing:

==

```
<input type="hidden" ID="hdnInterior" runat="server"  value="" />
```

==

```
string interiorValues = hdnInterior.Value;

XmlDocument xmlInterior = new XmlDocument();
xmlInterior.LoadXml(interiorValues);
```

====

How the hidden field [hdnInterior] is getting the values  [Javascript function]:

===

```
var interiorValues = "<InteriorXML>";

function StoreInterior()
{   
    var table = document.getElementById('dlInterior');

    if(jQuery('#dlInterior tr').length > 1)
    {
        for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++)
        {
            interiorValues += "<status>true</status>";

            var featureValue = jQuery(row.cells[1]).text();
            featureValue = featureValue.replace('*', '');

            interiorValues += "<FeatureValue>" + RemoveSpecialCharacter(featureValue) + "</FeatureValue>";
        }
        interiorValues += "</InteriorXML>";
        document.getElementById("hdnInterior").value = interiorValues;
    }
}
```

=====

## Sample XML

```
"<InteriorXML><status>true</status><FeatureValue>Air conditioning, single-zone manual front climate control</FeatureValue><status>true</status><FeatureValue>Assist handles, front passenger and rear outboards</FeatureValue><status>true</status><FeatureValue>Console, front center, with arm rest and concealed storage</FeatureValue><status>true</status><FeatureValue>Cruise control, electronic with set and resume speed</FeatureValue><status>true</status><FeatureValue>Cupholders 2 front and 2 rear and 2 additional in rear center armrest</FeatureValue><status>true</status><FeatureValue>Defogger, rear-window electric</FeatureValue><status>true</status><FeatureValue>Door locks, power programmable with lockout protection</FeatureValue><status>true</status><FeatureValue>Driver Information Center monitors 26 various systems including, Vehicle Information Menu (oil life, tire pressure, standard/metric units) and Trip Information Menu (trip 1, trip 2, fuel range, average fuel economy, instant fuel economy, average vehicle speed) and compass display</FeatureValue><status>true</status><FeatureValue>Floor mats, carpeted front</FeatureValue><status>true</status><FeatureValue>Floor mats, carpeted rear</FeatureValue><status>true</status><FeatureValue>Instrumentation includes speedometer, single trip odometer, fuel level, engine temperature and tachometer</FeatureValue><status>true</status><FeatureValue>Lighting, interior with theatre dimming, center-mounted dome, rear cargo area, dual front map lights and ambient lighting on integrated center stack</FeatureValue><status>true</status><FeatureValue>Mirror, inside rearview auto-dimming</FeatureValue><status>true</status><FeatureValue>Power outlets 4 auxiliary with covers, 12-volt, includes 2 front, 1 second row and one in the cargo area</FeatureValue><status>true</status><FeatureValue>Remote Keyless Entry</FeatureValue><status>true</status><FeatureValue>Seat adjuster, driver 2-way manual fore/aft adjustment power lumbar and power 2-way seat height adjuster (up/down)</FeatureValue><status>true</status><FeatureValue>Seat trim, cloth</FeatureValue><status>true</status><FeatureValue>Seats, front bucket</FeatureValue><status>true</status><FeatureValue>Seats, rear bench, 3 passenger with manual fore/aft adjustment, 60/40 split seatback and recline feature</FeatureValue><status>true</status><FeatureValue>Steering column, tilt and telescopic</FeatureValue><status>true</status><FeatureValue>Steering wheel, comfort grip vinyl with mounted cruise and audio controls</FeatureValue><status>true</status><FeatureValue>Theft deterrent system, vehicle, PASS-Key III</FeatureValue><status>true</status><FeatureValue>Visors, driver and front passenger illuminated vanity mirrors</FeatureValue><status>true</status><FeatureValue>Windows, power with driver and front passenger Express-Down</FeatureValue></InteriorXML>"
```

==================

The whole approach is working fine for all cases, but **sometimes I am getting issues like** :

> > There are multiple root elements. Line 1, position 2871

Any idea why the issue is it not coming for all cases, where as, when I am trying to reproduce it for same, I am not able to.

This clearly means that the root element has been repeated for some reason..Any idea where is it going wrong, I mean where something is cached or so..

How should I fix this? [With out adding a new root element to the XML]

I am working on ASP.Net 1.1 project.

Comment: Just a suggestion--> move `var interiorValues = "<InteriorXML>";` inside `if(jQuery('#dlInterior tr').length > 1){}` but before `for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++){...}`

Comment: Can it be a problem...the same name variable is used in Code behind to store the same information..

Comment: if `var interiorValues` is purely JS variable, how will it affect variable with same name in code-behind?

Comment: By `Can it be a problem` I meant is keeping that variable outside the function, as you pointed is the problem? I am not sure, as its not reproducable

Comment: if the function `StoreInterior()` is called async (using XHR), it will add `</InteriorXML>` multiple times and that can be an issue

Comment: @rt2800 - No, this method is only called from another JS method, which is called on a Save button click event from the form...What I doubt is, may be it is getting called multiple times when the user is clicking Save button..